# Git log count commits for a specific line in a file

Tags: git

There is a way to retrieve the commits for a specific line in a file as shown below. However, is there a way to count the number of commits for a specific line in a file using git log?

```
git log -L:40,50:filename.txt
```

Comment: What happens when a commit turns one line into three lines? Or when a commit adds 20 lines before the line in question and now line 40 is line 60? How are they to be counted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
git log -L 1,3:tests/requirements.txt | grep -Ec "commit [0-9a-fA-F]{40}"
```

What this'll do is grab all the commits that affect those lines, then isolate and count the commit IDs using `grep`. The `-E` flag makes `grep` use extended regexes, and `-c` makes it output a count instead of the matching lines.

This'll work for any variation of `git log` - for instance,

```
git log | grep -Ec "commit [0-9a-fA-F]{40}"
```

will give you the total number of commits in your repo,

```
git log tests/requirements.txt | grep -Ec "commit [0-9a-fA-F]{40}"
```

will give you the total number of commits involving that file, and so on. As long as your `git log` invocation includes full commit IDs, you're golden.

Comment: your grep|wc is so common there's an option for it, `|grep -c ^commit` will do it for you.